# ReKeying an RDD

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, rdd

I have a key value  RDD with 1 key and multiple values. How can I create a new RDD to have one of the values become the key and the key become a value?

Ex the existing RDD is `(16, (1002, 'US')), (9, (1001, 'MX')), (1, (1004, 'MX')), (17, (1004, 'MX'))]`. I want tomake a new RDD such that `(1002, (16, 'US')), (1001, (9, 'MX')), (1004, (1, 'MX')), (1004, (17, 'MX'))`

and the new RDD desired is

```
(1002, (16, 'US')), (1001, (9, 'MX')), (1004, (1, 'MX')), (1004, (17, 'MX'))
```

Answer (score 0):

rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1][0],(x[0],x[1][1])))